# Connect CSS with HTML in Apps Script with include

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script

I'm trying to add a CSS file inside an HTML form on Apps script. However, i don't to deploy the project as a Web App.
I'm trying to use the function include to apply the css style, but i have always the  peice of script above my form. Maybe it's because of the include which is not at the right spot but i don't know where to use it.
My html page is Formulaire.html, the css is css.html and the Gs code file is onOpen.gs

Here the onOpen.gs code :

```
function onOpen() {
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Formulaire')
      .addItem('Compléter', 'openForm')
      .addToUi();
}

function openForm() {

  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Formulaire')
    .setWidth(1500)
    .setHeight(1000);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .showModalDialog(html, 'Saisissez les informations nécessaires');
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}
```

Here the Formulaire.html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <base />
         <?!= include('css'); ?>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- MEANS -->
    <div class="category">
      <label for="inputMeans" class="ds-formcontrol-label">Means</label>
      <div style="width:100%;">
        <ul class="display-list" id="displayMeans"></ul>
        <input type="text" class="ds-input" id="inputMeans" list="datalistMeans" placeholder="Select here">
        <datalist id="datalistMeans"></datalist>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the css.html file which the css i want to apply :

```
<style>
    body {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        background-color: #1a237e;
    }
</style>
```

How can i solve these ?Thanks !

Comment: I've tried replicating your case on my end, and it seems that for the case of the include function (as well as doGet), the use of [scriplets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#printing_scriptlets) works if the [project is deployed as a web app.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#load_data_asynchronously_not_in_templates)

Comment: You could instead insert the CSS styling inside the `Formulaire.html` heading section to apply the styling format.

Comment: Is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/31363159

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
function openForm() {

  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Formulaire').evaluate()
    .setWidth(1500)
    .setHeight(1000);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .showModalDialog(html, 'Saisissez les informations nécessaires');
}
```

Comment: Simple as that ! Thanks a lot it works perfectly